# Laravel Loop through specific condition to display top 2

Tags: mysql, database, laravel

I am looking to display group stages (think world cup) and highlight the winners/losers. I am trying to display the top two teams in each group per year.

```
 $groupbwins = LoserData::select('team')->where('stage', 'group')->where('stageSeries', 'B')->where('ar', $id)->where('win', '1')->take('2')->get();
```

The take(2) yields the first two teams in each group that has a Win, but not the teams with the most wins per group. How can I loop throughand display the team with the most wins (tried orderby and groupby, but couldn't get that to work) or do I need to rearrange the db so that each group lists the winners from the group as the teams who won first in that group?

Comment: You will need to use orderBy in some capacity, but it may involve a raw query if you don't have the number of wins as a saved value in the db

Comment: The wins are tallied by 1. Is there a way add them together within the query and some how orderBy asc win total for the group? Thanks for responding to begin with btw.

Answer (score 1):

```
+----+----+------+-------+------------+-------------+
| id | ar | win  | stage | team       | stageSeries |
+----+----+------+-------+------------+-------------+
|  1 | 1  |    1 | group | carlton    | B           |
|  2 | 1  |    1 | group | carlton    | B           |
|  3 | 1  |    1 | group | west coast | C           |
|  4 | 1  |    0 | group | west coast | C           |
|  5 | 1  |    1 | group | west coast | B           |
|  6 | 1  |    0 | group | carlton    | A           |
|  7 | 1  |    1 | group | west coast | A           |
|  8 | 1  |    1 | group | carlton    | B           |
|  9 | 1  |    1 | group | carlton    | A           |
| 10 | 1  |    0 | group | west coast | C           |
| 11 | 1  |    0 | group | west coast | C           |
| 12 | 1  |    1 | group | west coast | A           |
| 13 | 1  |    1 | group | carlton    | A           |
| 14 | 1  |    1 | group | west coast | B           |
| 15 | 1  |    1 | group | west coast | B           |
| 16 | 1  |    1 | group | carlton    | B           |
| 17 | 1  |    1 | group | hawthorn   | B           |
| 18 | 1  |    1 | group | hawthorn   | B           |
| 19 | 1  |    1 | group | hawthorn   | A           |
+----+----+------+-------+------------+-------------+
```

You could use this Eloquent builder:

```
LoserData::selectRaw('team, sum(win) as winTotal')
  ->where('stage', 'group')
  ->where('stageSeries', 'B')
  ->where('ar', 1)
  ->groupBy('team')
  ->orderBy('winTotal', 'desc')
  ->take('2');
```

Which would produce this query:

```
select team, sum(win) as winTotal from `loser_datas` where `stage` = ? and `stageSeries` = ? and `ar` = ? group by `team` order by `winTotal` desc limit 2
```

Comment: This worked!! However to take it a step further, I have instances where multiple teams share the same record and my tiebreaker is score differential (goals for - goals against). Any idea on how to break where the list has specific values and reorder based on score differential? For example, I have 4 teams and multiple teams within the same group have w-l-t and 1-1-1.

Comment: Glad to help. Not sure I understand your update though?

Comment: It is very convoluted, sorry. I ended up converting w/l/t to points and ranking them that way. However, the tiebreaker is H2H matchups. I could not figure out how to code how a specific team did vs another team in that group, so I ended up creating a series of If-Statements for years. Definitely not the most efficient way.

Comment: Ok glad you got it sorted. Pleasemark my answer as correct if you think I answered your original question correctly!

Comment: Sorry man i tried, but I'm still a noob on here and am like 3 points away from being able to upvote....i'll do it when i can, i apologize for now